# Best way to write markdown content in Node.js

Tags: node.js, markdown

I have to write some markdown text in my Node.js script which will be rendered on UI with respective formatting.
Here are the two options I have explored so far:

Option 1:

```
module.exports = {
    status: "ENABLED"
    remediation: "**Adding markdown remediation here** ",
}
```

Option 2:

```
const remediation = "## this is another way which seems a bit better"
module.exports = {
    status: "ENABLED"
    remediation,
}
```

The second option renders a bit better but I am still struggling with a few things like defining new lines, adding code body etc.
Wanted to check if there can be a better way to include markdown text in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of creating your own wheels, please check [markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it).

```
npm install markdown-it --save
```

```
// node.js, "classic" way:
var MarkdownIt = require('markdown-it'),
    md = new MarkdownIt();
var result = md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!');

// node.js, the same, but with sugar:
var md = require('markdown-it')();
var result = md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!');

// browser without AMD, added to "window" on script load
// Note, there is no dash in "markdownit".
var md = window.markdownit();
var result = md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!');
```